# Why is my PHP/get request on jquery displaying a pop up with all of the php code in it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The following is my jquery/javascript code in my javascript file:

```
function userInput(){
        var name = form1.elements["name"].value;
        names1.push(name);
        console.log(names1);
        for(m=0; m<names.length; m++){
            console.log(names[m]);
            console.log(names1[0]);
            if (names[m] == names1[0]){
                    flag = "no";
                    m = names.length;
            }
            else{
                    flag = "yes";
            }
            console.log(names[m]);
            console.log(names1[0]);

    }
    $.ajax({
      url:"test.php", //the page containing php script
      type: "get", //request type
      success:function(result){
        alert(result);
                    console.log("post worked! :D");
    }
    });
    //run python training script here! send over names parameter
```

};

The following is test.php:

```
<?php
   echo("Hello World");
 ?>
```

In my html, I call UserInput() in a form so that when a button is clicked, this function runs. This part is working as expected. The issue that is occurring is that the Javascript runs the "test.php" code, however, when this is called, the website displays a pop up with all of the php code listed. I'm unsure of why this is occurring...I don't think it's because of the php code because I've tried multiple lines of PHP code that did not include echo and such..let me know if you need me to include any more information!

Comment: Are you running the code on a webserver with php correctly configured?

Comment: Are you doing this on a webserver that can process PHP?

Comment: what is your browser console showing.Does it show any error.What is the status code returned

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server language. If you haven't used them before, you probably aren't using a server, local or external. Check out here on how to set it up: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_install.asp Once it is setup, load all your code onto the server (which really just means you moving your code to a certain directory) and then try running it.